# Ubuntu 12.04 radeon HD 6670 Help!

Tags: ati, radeon

*Translated from Google:*

I have a radeon hd6670 and have not found how to make it work properly. Just install the OS and the screen is flashing purple. So I am only able to enter in safe graphics mode. Once there I tried everything:

Activated drivers that Ubuntu automatically detects from Additional Drivers, as a result it enters the desktop but it is all frozen, I can move the mouse but I can not interact with any icon.

I installed the drivers manually with guidance http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide and the result was the same as in the previous case.

Prove to the oneiric 11.01 Guide Installation Guide on the same page and again on desktop frizz

Finally installed the version 11.04 of the result http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide

The desktop looks and works but I have no 3D acceleration, I can not use Unity3D and all programs like POL give me error saying I have installed the wrong graphics

It is the first time I installed Ubuntu and I really like the OS, I do not want to reinstall windows if I can lend a hand I will thank you.

Comment: The only language allowed in this Q&A site is English. Please use google translate to see the answers and posting further details.

Comment: El único idioma permitido en este sitio de Q & A es el Inglés. Por favor, use el traductor de google para ver las respuestas y de contabilización más detalles.

Answer (score 2):

Please open `Ubuntu software center` and search for `fglrx` . Install `Ati binary driver` from there.

OR for better support

run the followings,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Reboot to see.

Comment: also you can try using the previous generation of drivers, the 12.4 version http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run following the same guide

Comment: @web-e.  Does he not have to purge the installation from the guide he used before following the instructions in our answer. Also when installing the binaries from USC does that also intsall the dependencies needed?

Comment: I have a fresh new install, ill try and let you know. Txs Guys

Comment: @StephenMyall yes it install the dependencies as well.

Comment: I hope it works, i dont know wy when i install the driver the screen freeze then the only way is to remove the driver an enter in safe graphics mode again

Comment: @Maxi you can try with x-swat repo drivers. I have updated the answer

Comment: I cant wait to go home an try it. Txs for the help

Answer (score 2):

The following Instructions below explain how install the latest ATI Catalyst Video driver on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. Please follow these commands...

## Step 1

Download Latest driver from [here](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run).

Create a folder name **Catalyst** in desktop and put the downloaded file in there.

## Step 2

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

After reboot, open a terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop
cd Catalyst
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

This will creat 3 **.deb** package in that following directory. Then, type:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.*deb
```

This will install this package in your machine. If any error occurred type `sudo apt-get -f install`. It will fix dependency problem. Then again install these package by typing `sudo dpkg -i *.*deb`.

If you don't get error in second time then you are good to go. Type:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
sudo reboot
```

After reboot check with:

```
fglrxinfo
```

You will see like this:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6000 Series 
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: when i get to this part "sudo dpkg -i *.*deb" i alwais get a responce that syas ther is no orginal module for this kernel. I dont know wath that meens. I that an error? Txs again for all your help